# how to read the text of the dropdown after selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am having multiple dropdown and upon bringing my mouse over the each dropdown I want to change the title of that particular dropdown to the selexted text and diaplay an alert message of the title.
How can I do that?

```
    <div> 
<select class="homepage" > 
    <option>No Match</option> 
    <option value="A">Test A</option> 
    <option value="B">Test B</option> 
    <option value="C">Test C</option> 
</select> 
</div> 
<div> 
<select name="homepage"> 
    <option>No Match</option> 
    <option value="1">Test 1</option> 
    <option value="2">Test 2</option> 
    <option value="3">Test 3</option> 
</select> 
</div> 
<div> 
<select class="homepage"> 
    <option>No Match</option> 
    <option value="J">Test J</option> 
    <option value="K">Test K</option> 
    <option value="L">Test L</option> 
</select>     
</div> 

    $('.homepage).bind('change', function(e){ 
        var newTitle=''; 
        $(".homepage option:selected").each(function () {                    
               $(this).attr('title',  $(this).text());
        }); 

    }); 

    $('.homepage).trigger('change');  

    $(".homepage").OnMouseOver()
    {
        ....
    }
```

Comment: `I want to change the title of that particular dropdown to the selexted text` isn't that the default behaviour?

Comment: No it isn`t.  my actualcode isn`t working.

Comment: a drop-down menu will always show the value of the selected item, at least on all OS'es I know. If that's not what you mean, what *do* you mean?

Comment: my question is: I want to change the title of that particular dropdown to the selected text and display an alert message of the title on mouseover.  I want it to be like that for all the dropdowns.  In my question I am having only 3 dropdowns, but in reality I amy have some 10 dropdowns on my page.

Comment: *Is the first part of your question not already happening by default? If not, what do you mean*

Comment: No, it isn`t, the title isn`t being changed by default.

Comment: Ahh, I understand now, you mean the `title` attribute of course, sorry. Okay, but then I'm not really clear what your question is: Isn't the code you show nearly there? What about it isn't working?

Comment: So what are you asking about - the `alert()` syntax? How to bind an event on mouse over?

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
  $('.homepage').change(function() {
    $(this).attr('title',text($(this).find(":selected").text()));
  });
```

This will fetch the selected (hence :selected) option from the .homepage dropdown and populate the title attribute of the dropdown.

Note: this assumes a single select not multi-select.

Pekka: title is very different to the currently selected item. The title attribute can be used for a number of uses such as tooltips and is not an attribute that is displayed.

Dave